# How to remove decimal values in google material charts

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization, column-chart

Is it possible to remove decimal numbers in vertical axis? I'm trying to display two charts but I don't know how to remove these decimal numbers because option **ticks** is not working in material charts.

**Code of script which is displaying charts:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            // Load the Visualization API and the line package.

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});//  google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']}); 


            // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Rok', 'Pocet'],

    <?php
    foreach ($chart_data as $data) {
          echo "['".$data["rok"]."', ".$data["pocet"]."],";

   }
     ?>



    ]);

    var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Rok', 'Pocet'],

    <?php
    foreach ($customers_data as $data) {
          echo "['".$data["rok"]."', ".$data["pocet"]."],";

   }
     ?>



    ]);     

    var options = {
                  chart: {
                        title: 'Chart 1',

                   },


                };

    var options2 = {chart: {
                        title: 'Chart 2',

                   },

                };



    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material')); 

    chart.draw(data,google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    var chart2 = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material2'));    

    chart2.draw(data2,google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options2));

            }

</script>
```

It's now displaying like this: [Current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TyH5.png)

And I want to just display 0, 1, 2...

Thank you for all suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

It has a setting you can add to your options var. For instance, if you want to add two digits float:

```
vAxis: {format:'0.00'}
hAxis: {format:'0.00'}
```

You can add as much as float digits you wish to, in the format attributes, such as:

```
vAxis: {format:'0.00000'}
vAxis: {format:'0.000'}
```

And if you wish to remove the decimals:

```
vAxis: {format:'0'}
vAxis: {format:'0'}
```

---

```
{format: ''}: displays numbers with no formatting (e.g., 8000000)
{format: 'decimal'}: displays numbers with thousands separators (e.g., 8,000,000)
{format: 'scientific'}: displays numbers in scientific notation (e.g., 8e6)
{format: 'currency'}: displays numbers in the local currency (e.g., $8,000,000.00)
{format: 'percent'}: displays numbers as percentages (e.g., 800,000,000%)
{format: 'short'}: displays abbreviated numbers (e.g., 8M)
{format: 'long'}: displays numbers as full words (e.g., 8 million)
```

---

```
var options2 = {
    chart: {
        title: 'Chart 2',
    },
    {
        hAxis: {
            format: '0'
        }
    },
    {
        hAxis: {
            format: '0'
        }
    }

};
```

### [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p5jk09bu/)

### [Number Formats Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats)

Comment: Thanks but when I added that to options it's not working: [link](https://i.imgur.com/kvmCS8H.png)

Comment: Sorry I put my question really wrong. I want to completely delete non-integer numbers so they will not appear in chart. When I tried: " format: '0' " it's now showing numbers twice in Chart 1: [link](https://i.imgur.com/yqOjniY.png) Chart 2 is showing normally without decimals on **vAxis** and I did not add anything to options there is only title attribute...it's very strange

Comment: If I understand correctly, `vAxis: {format:'none'}` doesn't work. In my case it simply prepended "none" before each number on the axis. `vAxis: {format:'0'}` did achieve the intended result however. If you want `none` as your format, I think a blank string is the correct value as per this e.g. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats.